# Selenium RemoteWebDriver against a Windows Service of ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, remotewebdriver, nssm

Context:

- Windows 10 Home;
- Visual Studio 2015 Community;
- C#;
- [NSSM](https://nssm.cc);
- ChromeDriver 2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129);
- Nuget package Selenium.WebDriver.2.53.1;
- Nuget package Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.2.23.0.1

I have used [NSSM](https://nssm.cc) to create a Windows Service wrapping chromedriver.exe, with the following settings:

```
Path: c:\bin\chromedriver.exe
Startup Directory: c:\bin
Arguments: --port=12942 --log-path=c:\temp\chromedriver.log --verbose 
Service Name: ChromeDriverService
```

In VS2015Community I've created a C# app as follows:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:12942");
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();            
options.BinaryLocation = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
options.LeaveBrowserRunning = true;
dc.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;            
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, dc);
```

When I step through the program, I get a `The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:12942/session timed out after 60 seconds.` on the `new RemoteWebDriver` line.

In the `c:\temp\chromedriver.log` I get the following:

```
[44.717][INFO]: COMMAND InitSession {
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "javascriptEnabled": true,
      "platform": "ANY",
      "version": ""
   }
}
[66.168][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "show_welcome_page": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_setting_values": {
         "geolocation": 1
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[66.171][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[68.099][INFO]: Can not set to US keyboard layout - Some keycodes may beinterpreted incorrectly
[68.099][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --load-component-extension="C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\scoped_dir5436_17406\internal" --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12772 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\scoped_dir5436_20664" data:,
[68.127][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12772/json/version
[70.154][DEBUG]: DevTools response: {

   "Browser": "Chrome/52.0.2743.116",

   "Protocol-Version": "1.1",

   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36",

   "WebKit-Version": "537.36 (@9115ecad1cae66fd5fe52bd9120af643384fd6f3)"

}


[70.155][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12772/json
[70.168][DEBUG]: DevTools response: [  ]

... a minute's worth of the above two lines removed ...

[128.264][INFO]: RESPONSE InitSession unknown error: unable to discover open pages
[128.264][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[128.264][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

I have a distant memory of having successfully talked to an NSSM-wrapped chromedriver.exe earlier this year. I can't find the code now. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `RemoteWebDriver` as your client. The address you give should be the Selenium Grid hub URL, not the chromedriver URL.

You should either [configure Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) to know about chromedriver, or switch from `RemoteWebDriver` to `ChromeDriver` as your client.

`ChromeDriver` connects to a service provided by chromedriver.exe on any machine, which may be where the confusion about `RemoteWebDriver` comes in. `RemoteWebDriver` means "any browser, anywhere, as chosen by a Selenium Grid hub using criteria that you provide". `ChromeDriver` means "any Chrome, in one specific location chosen by you".

If you switch to `ChromeDriver`, this code works well:

```
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
// service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;
service.Port = 12942;
var options = new ChromeOptions
{
    Proxy = new Proxy {Kind = ProxyKind.Direct}
};

return new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

There are lots more options you can provide to the service.

Aside: note that you configure the service to customize how `ChromeDriver` talks to chromedriver.exe; you configure `ChromeOptions` to customize how Chrome talks to the internet (or to your webapp).

Comment: I'm not using Selenium Grid (haven't read the friendly manual about that yet.) So is that approach hooking into the NSSM-wrapped ChromeDriverService Windows service or bypassing it in favour of an explicit Selenium ChromeDriverService?

Comment: Is it appropriate to add             
service.PortServerAddress = "http://localhost";
service.Port = 12942;

?

Comment: You don't need `PortServerAddress` if you're working on localhost. Updating the port is good, unless you're using the default.

Comment: However, trying to put Port into ChromeOptions doesn't work.

Comment: Running chromedriver.exe through NSSM is fine. Using `ChromeDriver` does not eliminate the requirement for chromedriver.exe. The naming is unfortunate, because `ChromeDriver` the class is a client, and chromedriver.exe is the server for the client. It is also a client, in that it sends requests to a running chrome instance. But that's outside of Selenium's problem domain; Selenium "stops" at the json service provided by chromedriver.exe.

Comment: Oops my bad. Port is for configuring the service, not the options. Onesec, I'll update the answer.